# Improving speed of python script

Tags: python

Is there anyway to improve the speed of the following. The code inserts a modifier to a http request. The modfiers are 5 digit email IDs. The goal is to apend each result into a JSON file.

I know getting rid of the Progessbar() will help, but i find the slow down worth the usefullness of the function. The Try Except Else section slowed it down again quit a lot, but idents has 4500 entries. Any ideas?

```
import urllib3
import json
import csv
from progressbar import ProgressBar
pbar = ProgressBar()

with open('blim2.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    idents = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    json_arr = []
    while True:
        try:
             for x in pbar(idents):
                http = urllib3.PoolManager()
                r = http.request('GET', 'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/mailbox/mailMessages/'+"".join(x)+'?include_body=1&api_token=token')
                mails = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
                json_arr.append(mails)
                with open('test2.json', 'w') as outfile:
                    json.dump(json_arr, outfile)             
        except:
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Comment: We need some context for what the code does (or should do). You repeatedly open the `'test2.json'` file within a `for` loop and overwrite all the existing contents each time. I/O will be slow, and it seems counter-productive to me?

Comment: Not only that, but I assume your `try`/`except` is in case one of the connections fails? If that's the case, you just start the entire `for` loop again, regardless of how many successful requests may have been made previously.

Comment: added the context to original question. So should I put the open 'test2.json' after the `for` loop has finished and write json_arr just once? Correct on the `try/except`. How would i structure it so it just resumes if the connection fails?

Comment: Yes, you will see a huge speed up if you just write to the file once at the end of the `for` loop. As for the `try`/`except` it depends on what you expect to happen. Is it likely that you have intermittent connection problems? Maybe you keep trying the same URL with a small sleep in the loop for a certain number of times and then abandon it and move to the next URL, I can't give you a definitive answer but starting again from scratch seems wasteful.

Comment: Just did that and saw a massive improvement. 20 to 85 iterations a minute. Ok i'll have to think about the `try/except` I don't think i understand how it works. I thought it would simply carry on with the next iteration, it didn't seem to start from scratch after I used it. Before I added it, the connection would break and the whole loop would stop.

Comment: Looking again, it's possible that `ProgressBar` maintains the CSV reader and can actually start back where it left off on an exception, so you might be right on that.

Comment: Just saying : but for improving code, there's a special site for this named code review.

Comment: You can find it here: [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the `while True` loop all the way to the inside to keep retrying a single request only. Also, write the file only once, at the end.

```
import urllib3
import json
import csv
from progressbar import ProgressBar
import time

pbar = ProgressBar()
base_url = 'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/mailbox/mailMessages/'
fields = {"include_body": "1", "api_token": "token"}

json_arr = []
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
with open('blim2.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    for x in pbar(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')):
        while True:
            try:
                r = http.request('GET', base_url + "".join(x), fields=fields)
                break
            except Exception:
                # wait a bit before trying again
                time.sleep(1)  # seconds
        mails = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
        json_arr.append(mails)
with open('test2.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_arr, outfile)
```

You should also look up what exception is actually being raised in your case and `except` only that. Otherwise you could be masking other problems. I already replaced your bare `except` with a `except Exception`, which at least allows the user to press Ctrl+C to abort the program.

Comment: Interesting thanks for this. However, it spits out this: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Robert Millard\Desktop\Pipedrive\testoid.py", line 12, in <module>
    for x in pbar(idents):
  File "C:\Users\Robert Millard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\progressbar\bar.py", line 447, in __next__
    value = next(self._iterable)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: @RobertMillard Ah, yes, that is because `csv.reader` is just a generator, apparently. Try with the edited code.

Comment: Awesome. 20 iterations to 122 iterations per minute. More to the point, i can learn form this :)

Comment: Thought i'd ask you directly. Why would this code spit out these errors now: recent call last):
  
  File "C:\Users\Robert Millard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
                                                                                                    | 546 Elapsed Time: 0:07:18
PS C:\Users\Robert Millard\desktop\pipedrive>

Comment: @RobertMillard It looks like the request returned `None`, which is obviously not a valid JSON object. As to why, no idea, sorry.